# How to implement "new style" Python AsyncIO iterator function from an "old style" class?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am trying to learn Python AsyncIO but having a lot of trouble with finding good tutorials that are up to date etc.

Let's say we have this "old style" async iterator class:

```
def chain(sink, *coro_pipeline):
    f = sink
    for coro_func, coro_args, coro_kwargs in coro_pipeline:
        f = coro_func(f, *coro_args, **coro_kwargs)
    return f

class sendable_deque(collections.deque):
    send = collections.deque.append


class AsyncIterator(object):

    def __init__(self, f, buf_size, *coro_pipeline):
        self.events = sendable_deque()
        self.coro = chain(self.events, *coro_pipeline)
        self.coro_finished = False
        self.f = f
        self.buf_size = buf_size

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        if self.events:
            return self.events.popleft()
        if self.coro_finished:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        while True:
            data = await self.f.read(self.buf_size)
            try:
                self.coro.send(data)
                if self.events:
                    return self.events.popleft()
            except StopIteration:
                self.coro_finished = True
                if self.events:
                    return self.events.popleft()
                raise StopAsyncIteration

# An example of a pipeline
def _parse_pipeline(parser, config):
    return (
        (parser['parse_basecoro'], [], {}),
        (parser['basic_parse_basecoro'], [], config)
    )
```

How is this now implemented? As I am lead to believe we use something more like:

```
async def async_parse(f, buf_size):
    while True:
         yield f.read(buf_size)

async def parse(f, buf_size):
    async with async_parse(f, buf_size) as pf:
        print(pf)
```

But the code in the class is using a chaining method which I believe is done with `asyncio.gather()`?

Any good modern guides/tutorials would be a great help also.

Comment: Can you please clarify how your old and new code is related? What are ``coro_pipeline``, ``sendable_deque``, and ``utils.chain``? Why do you explicitly call a coroutine via ``self.coro.send(data)``, and what's the point of the ``while True`` loop?

Comment: I don't really know.. thats why I asked the question. `coro_pipeline` is a function that adds functions to a module. `sendable_deque` is a class with an attribute `send = collections.deque.append`. `chain` "chains together a sink and a number of coroutines to form a coroutine pipeline". And as I said I'm learning, the teachng/learning resources for anything above basic asyncio are hard to find or too old.

Comment: Your new code looks good, but as for your old code I have no chance to understand it if you cannot explain it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The OP would like to convert an explicitly written async iterator into an async generator. I believe the answer is [this generator](https://pastebin.com/BpdBqraQ), but I cannot post it because the question is closed.

Comment: @user4815162342 I doubt the use of synchronous ``coro.send`` and pseudo-return via ``events`` is adequate with today's ``async`` support. Since the suggested code by the OP does not include it, it seems superficial to the problem. But it is impossible to say without knowing what it is.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `coro.send` is not necessarily "synchronous", it just uses a pre-async-await style of "coroutine" (sendable generator) to implement a processing pipeline, completely orthogonal to async/await. The fact that the author included a bridge to async/await shows that the design is quite compatible with async, and the OP is right to inquire how to do this with less code using an async generator. This is why I think the question is perfectly valid and should be reopened.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342, it seems people would rather vote to close than help. As we all know trying to learn python async is hard enough on its own but then we have so many tutorials and examples that are the "older style" methods that are now obsolete due to being in the ayncio library. As well as this, most resources for learning async are very basic. the basics are easy, but trying to convert this to "new style" async with barely any learning material..... I am only a person trying to learn and MisterMiyagi closing my question just means less people can learn new things!

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have edited my question to reflect your comments

Comment: @user4815162342, I've just looked at the code you shared on pastebin.. thanks i think that is exactly what I need!

Comment: @JamieLindsey MisterMiyagi is a prolific SO contributor, I'm 100% sure his intentions were constructive, urging an improvement of the question. With your edit there should no longer be any reason for the question to remain closed.

Comment: @user4815162342 Question is open again now, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Using an async generator the above hand-rolled async iterator can be expressed as follows (untested):

```py
async def async_iterable(f, buf_size, coro_pipeline):
    events = sendable_deque()
    coro = utils.chain(events, *coro_pipeline)
    done = False
    while True:
        while events:
            yield events.popleft()
        if done:
            break
        data = await f.read(buf_size)
        try:
            coro.send(data)
        except StopIteration:
            done = True
```

In the long run you might want to reconsider the use of bi-directional generators and replace them with native asyncio constructs such as [queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html).

Comment: Cheers, I am starting to really grasp asyncio now, I am now at the point of discovering when I should be using queue, gather, create_task etc